# What python built-in function can apply some function to every element of list in-place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have function **sqr(n)** and list **array**.
Is there python built-in function that apply **sqr(n)** to every element of **array** in-place (elements change inside the **array**)?
Some tricks with **map()** function or other built-in functions are also wanted.

Of course, this can be done using **map()** function, but it creates an iterator, and you get a new list (the old list doesn't change):

```
def sqr(n):
    return n ** 2

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array = list(map(sqr, array)) # have to reassign name to new list but elements don't change in old one.
print(array) # output: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

I want something like this:

```
def sqr(n):
    return n ** 2

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
some_built_in_function(sqr, array)
print(array) # output: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: I don't think so, lists ars immutable

Comment: @WasifHasan list's **aren't** immutable

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in function that does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in function, but you can accomplish the same result using `map` and slice assignment.

```
array[:] = map(sqr, array)
```

(If you needed an expression rather than a statement, you could use the monstrosity

```
array.__setitem__(slice(None), map(sqr, array))
```

which is essentially how the slice assignment is implemented.
)

Comment: Maybe Python needs a new assignment operator: `array [:]= sqr` :)

Comment: Well, that's what numpy is for pretty much

Comment: Unfortunately this ends up generating a temporary list that is immediately discarded, correct?  That might matter in some applications.

Comment: @MarkRansom No it does not in Python 3, where `map` returns an iterator and the assignment to a list slice does not create a new list.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I wanted, thank you :)

Comment: @MarkRansom Internally, `__set_item__` will just call `next` repeatedly on `map` object, which results in an on-demand call to `sqr` in order to set each element of `arr`.

Comment: That implies a slice that doesn't start at zero would fail spectacularly, but I just tried it and it worked fine.  Is `map` making a copy of the list before it iterates it?

Comment: No, the slice assignment just proceeds one element at a time, the same as `for i in range(len(array)): array[i] = sqr(array[i])`.

Comment: I was thinking of the case `array[1:] = map(sqr, array)` which I expected to behave like `for i in range(1,len(array)): array[i] = sqr(array[i-1])`.

Comment: Hm, that does surprise me. I would be very surprised if `map` does any caching, as it isn't necessary in general, and it cannot "precache" any data because that wouldn't be possible using the iterator protocol at all. I suspect `list.__setitem__` might save the incoming results before doing any assignments, probably so that it knows how much extra space may need to be allocate for the `list`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in function, but it's easy to write one yourself:

```
def mapinplace(l, fun):
    for i, val in enumerate(l):
        l[i] = fun(val)

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mapinplace(array, sqr)
```

Comment: Or `l[:] = map(fun, l)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are most likely operating on numbers, I'll post the obligatory numpy solution. Numpy isn't exactly built-in, but it's pretty close: the `@` operator in python was made for numpy, for example.

This solution will only be in-place if the input is a numpy array rather than a list:

```
np.square(x, out=x)
```

Most element-wise numpy operations can be done in-place like this.

Answer (score -2):

You can use list comprehension as follows to achieve this

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array = [i**2 for i in array]
print(array)
```

Comment: This creates a new list, rather than modifying the original list in-place. It just assigns the new list to the original name once it's complete. The distinction matters if you want to modify a list that was passed to a function as an argument, as assigning to the parameter doesn't affect the original list.

Comment: The list comprehension is effectively the same as `list(map(sqr, array))` that the OP mentioned in the question.